# Disable buffering for file descriptors in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, buffer

I may be misunderstanding what's going on here, but I feel it's got to do with pipe buffering. I have a script which uses several file descriptors (# 3 and above) for various logging levels. Depending on command line options, several of those may go to the same file, some to the console, some to `/dev/null`. I always have one of them (e.g. stdout) going to the file, and when I need to send several more to that file, I redirect them to stdout, rather than to the file. This is because I noticed that when I redirect several file descriptors to a file, they arrive out-of-order (which makes sense). That is to say I do

```
exec >/some/file 3>&1
```

rather than

```
exec >/some/file 3>/some/file
```

So far so good. However sometimes I need to take the error output of a command and send it to one of my custom descriptors, e.g. 3, which may be going to stdout (which in turn is going to a file). Then I get messages out of order. Messages from that command appear after messages from subsequent commands. Here's a small PoC. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

check_if_ordered() {
  sort -n -k1 -k2 test_out.txt > test_out_sorted.txt
  if ! diff test_out.txt test_out_sorted.txt >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Oops, messages are NOT in order" >&2
  else
    echo "Good, messages are in order" >&2
  fi
  rm test_out.txt test_out_sorted.txt
}

log() {
  while read msg; do
    echo "$msg"
  done
}

foo() {
  for i in {1..150} ; do
    echo "$1 $i"
  done
}

#### This always works OK, but can't use it in my scenario
echo "Redirecting command output to file"
foo "1" > >(log) > test_out.txt
foo "2" > >(log) >> test_out.txt
check_if_ordered

#### This is similar to what I need to do and always fails
echo "Redirecting stdout to file"
exec >test_out.txt
foo "1" > >(log)
foo "2" > >(log)
check_if_ordered
```

I should add that I know about external tools which can disable buffering for a command, but I can't use those in this case (my script needs to be as portable as possible and run on various distros).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#### This always works OK, but can't use it in my scenario
foo "1" > >(log) > test_out.txt
foo "2" > >(log) >> test_out.txt
```

The process substitutions here seem redundant as the next redirections override the redirection of stdout straight to the file. That is, the first one should be equivalent to `foo "1" > test_out.txt`.

```
#### This is similar to what I need to do and always fails
exec >test_out.txt
foo "1" > >(log)
foo "2" > >(log)
```

Here, I think the issue is that the process substitution runs asynchronously, and since the `while read; do echo` loop is slow, the first `log` is still running and reading from the pipe buffers when the second starts. It's similar to doing something like `echo foo > >(cat; sleep 1; echo hi)` on the command line, the `hi` appears well after the next prompt is displayed. Also, `wait` doesn't seem to help here either.

But I'm not sure why you need two copies of `log` in the first place? Wouldn't just one do:

```
exec >test_out.txt
exec 9> >(log)
foo "1" >&9
foo "2" >&9
```

(On my system, using `cat` instead of `while read; do echo` also at least hides the problem, since `cat` is much faster and reads in larger blocks. But that doesn't mean it would completely fix it, and you probably want to do something other than just an identical copy in `log`.)

> I should add that I know about external tools which can disable buffering for a command

If you mean stuff like `stdbuf -o0`, that only helps with buffering inside the process (in the C library), which I don't think comes into play here. The shell's `echo` should actually write the data out to the OS before returning.

Comment: I see, I hadn't realised that process substitution is asynchronous :-| I really like your proposal to just run log once in the background using `exec 9> >(log)`, that's way cleaner! Is there a way to redirect a FIFO file to log? Or should I just have `log` read from the FIFO instead of stdin and run it in the background?